# Multimeter and clamp give different AC current measurement

Tags: ac, current-measurement, multimeter, ac-motor

I am trying to measure the power output of an AC permanent magnet motor to a load (a resistor). To do this, I am measuring the current through the resistor, and the voltage across the resistor. To measure the current, I am using two methods: a benchtop digital multimeter which can measure AC current, and a clamp style meter which outputs a voltage that I measure on an oscilloscope.

The current measured by these two methods is about an order of magnitude different. The multimeter gives me ~200 mA while the clamp style meter gives ~ 3 A. I looked through the manual of the multimeter but couldn't find any information on the details of how the AC current measurement works to get an idea of what the problem might be. The output from the motor is ~ 20 Hz, and the voltage is ~ 20 V.

I had the multimeter set to autorange, but also tried all of the ranges individually. I also tried varying the sample rate. The clamp has two ranges, one which gives 100 mV / A output, and another which gives 10 mV / A output (I used the 100 mV/ A setting).

Link to multimeter manual (https://www.circuitspecialists.com/content/235770/siglent-sdm3045x-manual.pdf)

Link to clamp meter manual:
https://www.picoauto.com/download/documents/manuals/ta018-operators-manual-web.pdf

Has anyone on here encountered this problem before? Would definitely appreciate any thoughts on this. Thank you.
[image: Experimental Setup]

Update: called the company that sells the clamp meter (the technical support line) and they said they are not the original manufacturer and basically just read me the spec sheet. So maybe the next step is to try and figure out who makes it and call them.

Update #2: I decided to do a "sanity check" and measure the current drawn by a 75 Watt soldering iron, and I observed ~ 10 Amps drawn during heating, which seems clearly wrong (that would mean it is consuming 1 kW of power). So there it looks like there is a factor of 10 being lost somewhere, which I don't quite understand. I've attached a picture of the clamp meter below, and a picture of the oscilloscope screen. I guess its possible that the clamp meter is just labelled wrong but that seems unlikely too.

Update #3: OK, I was unaware that there was an option internally on the oscilloscope to scale everything by a factor of 10.. this was the problem, and it seems to be in agreement now.

Comment: Also, the waveform of the AC current clamp meter output as seen on the oscilloscope is a pretty smooth sinewave, so I don't think the discrepancy is due to crest factor as that is the one thing I've seen in the manual with respect to measurement inaccuracies

Comment: Why are you commenting on your own question? Edit the information into your post instead. Meanwhile, links to the multimeter user manual would be useful, a photo of your setups showing range selection, probe settings, etc., are kind of essential. A schematic of the setup is worth many words too. Hit the [edit] link. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: I suggest checking the frequency range your clamp meter is specified for. 20 Hz is quite low. Your multimeter is specified to 20 Hz, at 2% accuracy.

Comment: Is there any scaling going on at the O scope? Sometimes I'll accidentally use an incorrect scaling probe for example.

Comment: @Graham, I checked and it specifies 40 Hz minimum frequency for the clamp. But an order of magnitude difference at 20Hz seems odd, I'll try calling the manufacturer on Monday to see what they say.

Comment: @ Abel, I did double check the scaling of the vertical (voltage) divisions on the scope. The probe itself is the AC current clamp which plugs directly into the scope and specifies the voltage/amp so there is no intermediate probe.

Comment: What's the output voltage of the generator? Have you got the multimeter on a current scale? What's the voltage across the resistor, you can also infer the current from that if it's a good resistor.

Comment: @Ben the shown schematic must be wrong. The multimeter is connected like to measure current through wire, not voltage at resistor

Comment: @Neil, the output voltage is ~20V ac, and the multimeter is in current mode if that's your question. The voltage across the resistor is pretty much the same since there is nothing else in the circuit. I was under the impression that since it's an AC circuit I can't reliably use the resistance for that calculation because now it's impedance.

Comment: @schnedan, the multimeter is indeed measuring current, and I'm comparing the current measured by it and the clamp meter.

Comment: is your scope on 1x or 10x mode? It's not clear what the clamp would require. Are you multiplying the mV reading by 10? Also, have you done a measure with known currents in the correct frequency range? Like put a resistor on the secondary of a 12V 60Hz transformer and measure the current there.

Comment: @Sredni and Abel, thanks - I didn't know there was an internal scaling option, but I found that and sure enough it was at 10x...

Comment: The DVM will give the RMS value of the current, but the oscilliscope screen will display the peak-to-peak value, which will be about 2.8 times the RMS value (but some scopes may also give a digital readout in RMS...)